# iOS + Android 2D Game Engine

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform, game-engine

I already found some answers to this question here but they were all two years old or more.

Can anyone suggest me a cross platform (iOS+Android) mobile 2D game engine (Java or C++)?

I'd go with AndEngine but it supports Android only.

Thank you.

Comment: I think unity works for both

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). As you may have read from a few of the other threads in StackOverflow, it is one of the popular ones and there is sufficient material provided to assist you to get familiar with.

Here is their [Github page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki), which has loads of information to get you started (see external tutorials in the wiki). I would also like to recommend dermetfan's libGDX channel for a basic introduction that I have found useful with certain components (search dermetfan libGDX in youtube, would provide link but I'm restricted to two links).

Personally, I have used libGDX as a mobile 2D game engine for a work project, and I've found it really nice. Hope this helps!